# Time based GPS location in background (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gps, background-process

I want to create an (game based) iPhone application which sends your GPS location on a specific time (like 3-5 times a day) to a server. I found an apple page explaining some functionality to run in the background like location, music and VOIP.

I need the GPS to be accurate on the meter.

Can someone help me with a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your usage of the location. If you monitor actively, kiss the battery of your user goodbye. Very detailed accuracy, even bigger hit to battery. The backgrounding of location is all or nothing as far as accuracy goes.

Less hit, less accuracy is -startMonitoringForSignificantLocationChange. May not be accurate enough for you.

Better depending on usage, region monitoring. Triggers event on entry or exit of defined region.

You don't have the benefit of accuracy and timed location based events. You can do it, but is going to require a lot more effort on your end.

Comment: The idea is to get someone's location at a specific time not update when his location changed significantly. The idea was when the background function has a accurate location. Turn the GPS off and schedule a next update after a few hours?

Comment: I realize that, but I'm afraid that Apple's backgrounding services won't lend themselves to this type of implementation.

Comment: What IS a significant change? (meters/kilometers?)

Comment: All the specifics haven't been listed. But it is generally regarded as change in cell tower connection, connect to wifi, or when another app requests current location. That data is shared via the significant change. It is fairly accurate, but the timing can't be counted on because it is based on movement of the user. No movement, no updates.

Answer (score 0):

While this is untested, I am planning an app with a similar need. My solution is that on a significant location change, the app will determine what interval exists between the update timestamp, and when I care to know the users location (5pm for instance). If that's below some threshold, it will go into startUpdatingLocation mode (full power, battery draining, which is why that threshold is important) and then, on each location update, check if that target time has passed. if SO, send the update to your server, and go back to monitoring for significant changes. The catch is that if it still requires some movement to trigger the significant change update...so it isn't a perfectly reliable solution, but it may work depending on how you're using the data

Comment: What IS a significant change? (meters/kilometers?)

Comment: Is there anything about the game that would force movement? Or any commonality you expect across users that might lend itself to some other solution? Could you use push notifications to get the user to interact, and get a location update at that time? Or does the update have to be more subtle?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "schedule background work". iOS doesn't allow it.

The solution is to set yourself up for notification on significant change (which is *some* hit to the battery, but it's not horrible), and then only DO anything with that at occasional intervals.

Comment: you can schedule background work: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13 I quote "An application running in the background can post a local notification to get the user’s attention."

Comment: Yeah, but not like "run again in three hours". You can register for background time, but you get like 10 minutes.