# iPhone Getting Location Periodically

Tags: iphone, cllocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time based GPS location in background (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560154/time-based-gps-location-in-background-iphone)

I am trying to get the iPhone's location periodically. When the app goes into background, a new thread is created and wants to get user's location, and then goes to sleep for X minutes. Then wakes up, gets user's location again and goes back to sleep.

When the thread wakes up, I need to get the location. I can't user the CLLocationMangerDelegate because that updates on its own and calls the delegate method whenever it wants. I need to somehow get the user's location whenever the thread wakes up.

Can anyone help me please? I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know it's not possible to achieve this through a scheduled method call (as you mentioned). i had similar problem and i solved it by having a `CLLocationManager` that triggers whenever the user's location is changed for about 1 KM.

the drawback of this implementation is the battery consumption.